# How is it suggested to inherit from an implicit style in Xamarin.Forms XAML?

Tags: xaml, inheritance, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having some issues inheriting from an implicit style defined in an Application ResourceDictionary. I have tried a couple of different approaches, but each has been unsuccessful in one form or another.

## Attempt 1: Inherit from implicit style

#### Application ResourceDictionary

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#1386F1" />
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="HeightRequest">
      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="30" Android="50" />
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger TargetType="Button" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor">
          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color" iOS="#E8E8E8" />
        </Setter>
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

#### Page ResourceDictionary

```
<Style x:Key="LoginButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#024886" />
    <Setter Property="Margin">
      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,5" />
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

#### Page Control

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource LoginButtonStyle}" />
```

#### Result

Throws exception "StaticResource not found for key {x:Type Button}". This is how I remember doing it in WPF, but I'm assuming this isn't supported in Xamarin XAML.

## Attempt 2: Inherit from common explicit style

#### Application ResourceDictionary

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <!-- Same as Attempt 1 -->
</Style>
<!-- This implicit style causes issues with the inheritence of the Trigger in the above explicit style. When it's commented out, everything works fine. -->
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}" />
```

#### Page ResourceDictionary

```
<Style x:Key="LoginButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}">
    <!-- Same as Attempt 1 -->
</Style>
```

#### Page Control

```
<!-- Same as Attempt 1 -->
```

#### Result

Everything works except for the Trigger. However, when I remove the implicit style the Trigger magically starts working again. I'd rather not have to specify the explicit style on every Button, though. I believe this is just a bug, but I wanted to make sure before I take the time to prepare a bug report.

Any ideas?

[Question in Xamarin Forums](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/74481/how-is-it-suggested-to-inherit-from-an-implicit-style)

Comment: Hmm on android the trigger is working. Can't verify it on iOS right now. As a workaround (before you declare the trigger on each button), you could try to use a behavior. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/behaviors/creating/

Comment: The default background of a disabled button on Android is already the color I have specified in the trigger for iOS (#E8E8E8), so I'm not sure it's working there either. Since I am applying the trigger to iOS only, I have not tested if it works on Android.

Comment: I changed it to magenta and its working, too :)

Comment: And if you read the source code, you see that it is implemented. So maybe it is a bug. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Style.cs#L36

Comment: Attempt 3: did you try defining trigger action in code?

Comment: @nishantvodoo No, I didn't. I am asking for the suggested method of defining the inheritance in XAML because that is what I prefer.

Comment: Just in case you decide using trigger in code. https://blog.xamarin.com/triggers-in-xamarin-forms/ (look Define the TriggerAction in code) It is actually as simple and as manageable as in XAML

Answer (score 4):

First of all, thanks for the nice summary!

In my opinion this is a **bug**, which can be prevented with a little **trick**:

```
<!-- Base Style -->
<Style x:Key="BaseButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <!-- Define base button style... -->
</Style>

<!-- Implicit Style -->
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}"></Style>

<!-- Inherited Style -->
<Style x:Key="InheritedButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}">
    <!-- Extend base button style... -->
</Style>
```

Basically, the idea is to create a common **explicit base style**, which gets **inherited by an implicit style** afterwards. Therefore, all buttons are automatically applying the BaseButtonStyle, which is additionally extensible.

*Attention*: The implicit style has to be created after defining the base style.

**EDIT**: Apparently this is the *same solution as #2* already provided before. So, the **Trigger issue** is not fixed, which seems to be a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you please specify to which bug you are referring? You have listed the same code as I listed in Attempt #2, so I fail to see how the `Trigger` bug I referred to would be prevented with what you have provided.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the clarification. Sorry, I oversaw that my solution is exactly the same as yours, because I mainly focused on the main question.

As I am solely relying on data binding, I have not realized that triggers are not working.